# Solr - How to use "dir" attribute of <lib> tag, in solrconfig.xml

Tags: java, search, solr

I tried to use the DIH feature of solr, but the `<lib>` tag in `solrconfig.xml` confused me a little.

---

**Paths:**

I install solr under `solr_5.2.1\`.

Core is created at `solr_5.2.1\server\solr\search_cn\`

`solrconfig.xml` is at `solr_5.2.1\server\solr\search_cn\conf\solrconfig.xml`

DIH lib is at `solr_5.2.1\dist\solr-dataimporthandler-5.2.1.jar`

---

I thought following `<lib>` should be used to import DIH lib:

`<lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />`

But, it don't, instead, following works:

`<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />`

---

Any one can help to explain about that? Thx.

---

**@Update:**

If the answer by `@abhishek bafna` is correct, then I have another doubt:

When I create a lib folder at: `solr_5.2.1\server\solr\search_cn\lib\`.

And include it via `<lib dir="../lib/" />`, it could found the jars inside.

But according to the answer, it should be `<lib dir="./lib/" />`, right?

Could you help to explain that, I want to make it clear to avoid future config issue, thx.

---

**@Summary:**

I did a test according to answer of `@abhishek bafna`.

And following is my summary, (with solr **5**.2.1):

- `<lib>`'s `dir` is relative to instance_dir, where the solr.properties is found.
- by default `instance_dir_base/lib/` will be searched to find jars, and **no need** to config it via `<lib>`.
- any other folder, need to use a `<lib>` to config properly, if want to load jars from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directories are resolved relative to solr `instanceDir`. The `instanceDir` is place where it founds the `core.properties` file. It looks for a `conf` folder inside the `instanceDir` and creates the `data` (index data) directory.

Comment: That makes sense, even though I didn't see description in official document.

Comment: I append the question with a little update, would you mind to take a look at that, thx.

Comment: @EricWang I tried out configuration which you have updated. My observation are following: You can put jars into instanceDir (which contains your conf dir and core.properties) or create a lib folder. Solr was able to load the jars automatically, without specifying anything into the solrconfig file. But when I created another directory into lib then I needed to specify the correct dir in <lib> directive. Please try it out by yourself and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I did a serial of test this morning, and appended my summary in the question. Basicly, you are right, exception that the `instance_dir/` itself is not a default folder that would be searched, but `instance_dir/lib/` will be searched as you said. Any other folder, include sub folders of `instance_dir/lib/` won't be searched by default. After change config or jar location, I think a restart might be needed to make it 100% take effects.

Comment: Thank you so very very much